# How to use internal controller on ingress-nginx GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, pulumi

Hi everybody I am deploying ingress-nginx version 4.2.5 and I'm facing an issue, I read the documentation and they say it is possible to have both internal and external controllers using the same ingressClass, I am deploying on GCP using pulumi but also have tried using helm and the same results
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
I verified that I have both controllers in place as you can see here

```
NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-test-controller            LoadBalancer   10.132.134.99    34.138.195.84   80:30345/TCP,443:31306/TCP   103s
ingress-nginx-test-controller-internal   LoadBalancer   10.132.133.193   10.128.0.131    80:30851/TCP,443:30081/TCP   104s
ingress-nginx-test-controller-metrics    ClusterIP      10.132.193.30    <none>          10254/TCP                    105s
```

but when I create an ingress and set IngressClass to nginx-internal it gives me the following error

```
"Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="XXXX/XXXX" error="no object matching key \"nginx-internal\" in local store"
```

Comment: feel free to update the status of the question if the below answer satisfies your answer or an upvote if found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If Nginx ingress internal `ingressclass` does not exist you can create the one with

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: internal-nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/internal-ingress-nginx
```

Make sure you are pointing to right controller.

Further you can use the same `ingressclass` to **ingress**

Here you can refer the official doc : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/